# gerrit scripting: avoid adding to CC when posting comment on review

Tags: bash, gerrit

I can scriptably access, list and post comments on gerrit. All is good.
However, when I use my function below, I am always added as CC (carbon copy).
How can I remove myself or avoid being added as CC altogether?

```sh
# Usage: read (multiline) comment from stdin, post that to review named by argument
function gerrit_send_comment
{
    local sha=$1

    function generate_json {
    # Format description: http://gerrit.ci.kitenet.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#review-input
    # Heredoc's EOF must be not be indented!
cat << EOF
{
  "notify": "NONE",
  "tag": "autogenerated:mpedbot",
  "message": $(cat - | json_escape_to_single_string)
}
EOF
    }

    cat - \
    | generate_json \
    | ssh -p ${GERRIT_PORT} ${GERRIT_HOST} gerrit review $sha --json
}
```